# JQuery Slide Panel with more than one panel

Tags: jquery, slidetoggle

I have this jquery code which slidetoggles the content on click.  This code works, I just want to know if there is a simpler way to do it.  I have tried slice() with no luck.  I'm trying to figure out a way to do this without having to write code for each item I want to toggle.

Thanks,

Kevin

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $("div.accord_panel").hide();
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("p.accord_header:eq(0)").click(function () {

            $("div.accord_panel:eq(0)").slideToggle("slow");
            $("div.accord_panel:eq(1)").hide();
            $("p.accord_header:eq(1)").show();
        });
        $("p.accord_header:eq(1)").click(function () {
            $("div.accord_panel:eq(1)").slideToggle("slow");
            $("p.accord_header:eq(0)").show();
            $("div.accord_panel:eq(0)").hide();
        });

    });
</script>
```

And the CSS:

```
    p.accord_header
    {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        font-family: 'Helvetica Neue' , Helvetica, Arial, Sans-Serif;
        color: #615E5A;
        font-size: 9pt;
        font-weight: bold;
        background-color: #f3f0ed
    }
    div.accord_panel
    {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        font-family: 'Helvetica Neue' , Helvetica, Arial, Sans-Serif;
        color: #615E5A;
        font-size: 9pt;
        display: none;
        background-color: #f3f0ed
    }
```

and HTML:

```
<p style="text-align: -webkit-auto;" class="accord_header"><strong><span>+ El Salvador/San Diego de Tenango Task Force</span><br />
<br />
</strong></p>
<strong>
</strong>
<div class="accord_panel"><strong><span>In partnership with Agros, Int'l since 2001, UPC has come alongside this rural village to encourage them as they move toward economic self-sufficiency. &nbsp;Most importantly we send service teams in January and July to renew friendships, share the love and gospel of Jesus Christ and participate in village activities.<br />
<br />
<br />
Julie Thomas // 425.881.6185</span><br />
</strong>
</div>
<p style="text-align: -webkit-auto;" class="accord_header"><strong><span>+ El Salvador/San Diego de Tenango Task Force</span><br />
<br />
</strong></p>
<strong>
</strong>
<div class="accord_panel"><strong><span>In partnership with Agros, Int'l since 2001, UPC has come alongside this rural village to encourage them as they move toward economic self-sufficiency. &nbsp;Most importantly we send service teams in January and July to renew friendships, share the love and gospel of Jesus Christ and participate in village activities.<br />
<br />
<br />
Julie Thomas // 425.881.6185</span><br />
```

Answer (score 1):

here is your answer. [Jquery Tools](http://flowplayer.org/tools/tabs/index.html), easy to use and ligthweight.

Answer (score 1):

You can just pass in an event argument to the click function to be able to use the `event.target` property to get the clicked element, then get the next`.accord_panel` sibling of that element to slide down after sliding up all the panel elements:

```
$("p.accord_header").click(function(e) {
    $("div.accord_panel").stop(true, false).slideUp();
    $(e.target).closest('p').next('.accord_panel').stop(true, false).slideDown();
});
```

This will work with any number of headers and panels.

[**See example here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/hTzVg/)